# Emberjs and jQuery UI clone helper

Tags: jquery-ui, ember.js, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to get jqueryui drag and drop to work with emberjs. I have a fiddle set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/XMgwV/13/ but I cant seem to get the drop event to fire. 
The mixin is from this demo: http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/03/10/using-ember-js-with-jquery-ui/

Edit:
If I change the jQueryUI draggable helper function to 'original' it works as expected. It seems to be a problem with jquery ui `.clone()` and ember, as pointed out in #7 [here](http://codebrief.com/2012/03/eight-ember-dot-js-gotchas-with-workarounds/). The safeClone method in the codebrief blog post does not seem to [solve the problem fully..](http://jsfiddle.net/XMgwV/22/)

Anyone knows how to get this to work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your example will work if you add:

```
    clone.removeClass('ember-view');
```

to the safeClone helper.

Here's a jsfiddle that should solve the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Wu2cu/

Comment: great find! hopefully it doesnt break anything :) I doubt it will

Comment: I'll be implementing it in a project the next few days, will let you know if any issues arise

Comment: Do you know why the drop event fires twice? Havent figured that out yet. Im getting that behavior in both Chrome and Safari

Comment: henk pointed out to me that the jquery event fires once and the dom event once. He even made a fiddle demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/Wu2cu/2/

Answer (score 2):

I've had to fix the jQuery UI wrapper to make it work. But all I could come up with was a dirty hack.

I had to turn

```js
var ui = jQuery.ui[this.get('uiType')](options, this.get('element'));
```

into

```js
var ui = $(this.get('element'))[this.get('uiType')]();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MSch/LrHTB/1/

Comment: this works for me! I can keep building my application while you smart guys figure out the best way to do the behind the scenes stuff :)

Comment: Keep in mind that this will disable the options gathering for ALL jQueryUI elements.

Comment: also, for future reference this.$() == $(this.get('element'))

Comment: The flickering of the jsfiddle also seems to disappear when this line is changed.